# How to clear billing form validation errors when using Magento UI components

Tags: magento2, checkout, billing-address

Default magento checkout behavior when using **new customer billing address form** (related to newCustomerBillingAddress name in the local storage).

[image]

1. we uncheck **"My billing and shipping address are the same"** checkbox
2. the **new customer billing address form** is shown
3. we start to fill some data into the fields. for example **"first name"**.
4. we remove this **"first name"** value and we see validation error
5. we click again **"cancel"** at the bottom or the checkbox **"my billing and shipping address are the same"**
6. form is hidden
7. we uncheck the **"my billing and shipping address are the same"**
8. we see the **form** and the **validation errors**

My questions are related to step nr 7 and 8.

**Q1: how to clear validation errors in the form when action in step 7 happens and we see form (step 8) ?** How to do it when we show form using our custom functions to show/hide form and select different addresses (when user is logged) ? I would like example of function that I could put into view/billing-address.js that will clear validation error in/after step nr 8.

**Q2: Why if user click "cancel" magento saves the changed input values? I guess it's because keyUp event in Magento Ui?**

I've made some changes that if:

**p1.** user fill the form and click "save". data is valid so store in some observable/localStorage

**p2.** user edits the form data. Ex. He removes the first name field.. but than he clicks cancel button

in **p2 step**  I compare previous valid form data to the new form data.

If the field has different value than I restore the valid one and I have to trigger keyUp for fields that were modified to hide the validation error.

I know I do it the wrong way... but how can I access in **billing-address.js** every billing address form's field (to set new value / clear validation / revalidate) ?

**extra question** - why magento2 knockout's **billing-address.js** methods are executed in every payment method scope (**this.dataScopePrefix**) even if we turn on in store only one or two or X payment methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've asked a bit of a mouthful there -- probably too much for a single Stack Exchange question, so I'm going to concentrate on teaching you how to reset the initial state of the form so things no longer appear invalid if there's a blank value.  If you're interested in the whys, you'll need to get up to speed on the fundamentals of UI Components and `x-magento-init` scripts.  My [Magento 2 UI Components](http://alanstorm.com/series/magento-2-ui/) and [uiElement Internals](http://alanstorm.com/series/magento-2-uielement-internals/) series are a good place to start. The following assumes you have some familiarity with these systems -- if there's something confusing below then the above articles (as well as the other [Magento 2 articles](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2/)) will probably have the information you're looking for.

In the Checkout Application, each form field is represented by a view model, and one-or-many view model templates.  You can see this in [Commerce Bug's KO Scopes](http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/commerce-bug-3) tab.

[image]

The firstname's view model is an object derived from the constructor function returned by the `Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract` RequireJS module.  You can find that model's source code here

```
vendor/magento//module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/abstract.js
```

The `reset` method is the one we're interested in.  This will reset a field's validation state.  You'll need to figure out the full `uiRegistry` string identifier for the specific model (again, Commerce Bug is useful here), use that string to fetch the instantiated view model, and then call the reset function.  For the `checkmo` form, the following program (easily adapted into a `define` module if you're going to use it in your application) will do that for the `firstname` field.

```
requirejs(['uiRegistry'], function(uiRegistry){
    uiRegistry.get('checkout.steps.billing-step.payment.payments-list.checkmo-form.form-fields.firstname').reset();
});
```

Of course, you'll likely want to fetch each view model that's part of a particular form -- the following is a start on that.

```
uiRegistry.get(function(viewModel){
    var parentName = viewModel['parentName'] ? viewModel['parentName'] : '';
    if(parentName.indexOf('checkout.steps.billing-step.payment.payments-list.checkmo-form.form-fields') === -1){
        return;
    };       
    console.log(viewModel);
});
```

This uses the `uiRegistry`'s callback feature to search for all view models with a parent of `checkout.steps.billing-step.payment.payments-list.checkmo-form.form-fields`.  Some of these may not be form elements, but we'll leave that problem as an exercise for the questioner.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great answer!  Hopefully I will find an answer for my extra question in your articles.